# simple_format and embed's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, embed, wysiwyg

I've tried searching the web for a solution for this but havent been able to find any way of combining this.

Im printing html from a wysiwyg editor and found the simple_format helper to print the HTML with paragraphs etc. The problem is that it strips embed tags from the code aswell.

Do any of you know a way to print content from a WYSIWYG that adds paragraphs, br's, strong/bold and keeps all media such as images, embed's, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the WYSIWYG already add the paragraphs and linebreaks? Wich WYSIWYG are you using?

Comment: The default one from WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

Incase anyone is interested i solved it with:

```
<%= simple_format(content.post_content, {}, {:sanitize => false}) %>
```